# Show build output when running a Java project in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

I created a small Java project in NetBeans. When I run it, there appears no compiler log.

I'd like to see the compiler output even when I decide to run the project. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NetBeans `Menu/Window/Output`